# New Dialog-Box in Reopen Votes Review Queue Doesn't Close

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-reopen, popups

I've just been doing some reviews in the "Reopen Votes" queue and, during this process, I noticed a change to a new pop-up when I select "Reopen".  The new pop-up has a much nicer look:

[image]

However, after clicking the "Vote to reopen" button, the dialog doesn't close! The next post in the queue comes along, but the dialog(ue) box stays active. (If I change my mind and click "Cancel," then it closes properly.)

I'm assuming this is a bug, not a feature!

Comment: Deleting and reposting would be faster.

Comment: This new banner shows on other sites too I think. I'm sure I saw it this morning on SFF.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I hope it didn't mention Stack Overflow in that banner?

Comment: Also on a related issue, the banner for audits is still the old one which makes reviewing audits easy to find.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Then shall I leave it here? (Still learning how these Meta sites work!)

Comment: @Mast It was a few hours ago but IIRC it did say SFF yeah.

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica Technically here or SO meta is fine but as (if I am indeed remembering correctly) it is a network change, here is fine.

Comment: Yup, if it has been reproduced on other sites it's a network-wide bug and should remain here.

Comment: Or the AI powering software development for SE is nudging you towards leaving it closed.

Comment: @muru Actually, I think the danger is more that folks will think their click didn't register and click again - thus inadvertently nominating both that and the next item for reopening … and possibly *ad nauseam*?

Comment: Also reproduced on CR.SE: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9413/vote-to-reopen-prompt-bug

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out this was broken on question pages as well, but there we reload the page so the dialog *looks* like it closes.

I pushed a fix up into the build pipeline. It'll go into production with the next build. Thanks for the report!